# install4j: How can I use Check JDBC Connection with a jdbc driver added during install time

Tags: java, install4j

i am evaluating install4j in a project that needs to add the jdbc-Driver ( eg. Oracle ojdbc ) during install time. The only way in install4j to use the "Check JDBC Connection" action way seems to add the driver during buildtime.  ( via Installer -> custom code&resources ). How can i add the driver during install time ?

Answer (score 0):

You can call

```
context.addToClassPath(new File("<path>"));
```

in a "Run script" action that has to be executed before the JDBC driver is required.